# Sharing class between different activities

Tags: java, android

I'm currently creating a game that uses multiple activites.
The different activities need to all be able to communicate with my main ConnectionManager class that sends stuff to my backend server.

The connection is currently only available in one of the activites like this:

```
connectionManager = new ConnectionManager( this );
connectionManager.start();
```

So what i want is, in the first activity the app should start the connectionManager and keep it running. Then when the user switches to another activity that activity needs to be able to send data to the connectionManager.

One possible way would be passing data when changing intents:

```
startActivity(new Intent(gameLobbyManager.this, LobbyManager.class).putExtra( key,value)));
```

But then i cannot pass the entire class to the new Intent which is needed in my case.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Firstly, your `connectionManager` is not a `class`, but is an `object` - an instance of `class`. Then I'd suggest to move your staff that needs to be shared across all app to the `Service`.

Comment: Exactly! - and use for instance service binding to interact with the instance: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html. Broadcasts might be another option: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: If your class `ConnectionManager` is a normal Java class you could implement `Parcelable` or the `Serializable` interface and pass it through the `Intent` by using `Intent#putExtra(String, parcelable)` or `Intent#putExtra(String, Serializable)`.
Unless you really want to have this object shared in a "global" way, this is generally the best solution (and best practice for that matter).
One thing: you should always favour `Parcelable` over `Serializable`, as the implementation is up to 10 times faster.